# jQuery and JavaScript inside infowindow of Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to run some jQuery and JavaScript code in HTML inside `infowindow` on my map that has lots of markers.

The problem is that code is working when I click second time on marker to open `infowindow`. 
This is part of code that needs to center the image inside infowindow:

```
infowindow.setContent(boksic);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
var images = $(".slika_centiraj_karta");
for(var c = 0; c<images.length; c++) centerImage(images[c]);
```

Comment: You'll have to post more code than that.  Where's the jQuery you're talking about?  How about a link or a demo?

Comment: Sorry but I can't post more cod than that but I just foud the solution;
`infowindow.setContent(boksic);
   
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
 
  setTimeout(function () { 
     var images = $(".slika_centiraj_karta");
  for(var c = 0; c<images.length; c++) centerImage(images[c]);
  }, 150);`

Comment: ok I will but neead to wait for 5 more hours because of reputation :-(

Comment: It's appreciated and you'll pick up more rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I foud the solution; Seams like infowindow haw some timeout itself before it opens and i had to ad some timeout on my function like this:

```
infowindow.setContent(boksic);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
setTimeout(function () { 
var images = $(".image_center_infowindow");
for(var c = 0; c<images.length; c++) centerImage(images[c]);
}, 150);
```

The function `centerImage` centers the image on a fixed `<div>` depending on image orientation.

There is also a better solution with google maps infowindow event listener that waits til infowindow is loaded and then executes the code:

```
infowindow.setContent(boksic);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function(event) {
var images = $(".image_center_infowindow");
for(var c = 0; c<images.length; c++) centerImage(images[c]);
});
```